# Angular components doesn't appear after migrating to Angular

Tags: angular

I have been working on a new spotify-like project called StreamusX

Firstly I just created Html & CSS layout of the website. Then I wanted to move it to Angular. 
However, after copy & pasting, I get only a blank page without any component. They just disappear.

Here's my app component. HTML

> ```
> <div id="wrapper">
>
>   <div id="main">
>     <app-navbar></app-navbar>
>     <div id="content">
>       <app-albums>Loading...</app-albums>
>     </div>
>   <div class="player fixed">
>     <div class="progress-bar">
>       <span class="active-progress"></span>
>     </div>
>     <a href="#">
>       <div class="song-cover">
>         <img src="../assets/images/img1.jpeg">
>       </div>
>       <div class="song-details">
>         <ul>
>           <li class="artist-name">Ed Sheeran</li>
>           <li class="song-name">Happier</li>
>         </ul>
>       </div>
>
>     </a>
>     <div class="main-action">
>       <div class="btn-group">
>         <button><i class="fas fa-step-backward"></i></button>
>         <button><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
>         <button><i class="fas fa-step-forward"></i></button>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="other-action">
>       <div class="btn-group">
>         <button><i class="fas fa-random"></i></button>
>         <div class="volume-bar">
>           <span class="volume"></span>
>         </div>
>         <button><i class="fas fa-step-forward"></i></button>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>
>   </div>
>
> </div>
> ```

Here's my app.component.css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
#main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "navbar main"
        "navbar main"
    ;
}

app-navbar{
    grid-area: navbar;
}

#content{
    grid-area: main; 
} */

/* Here goes player styles */

.player{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(220px, 1fr));
    background: var(--primary);
    color: white;
    min-height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
}

.progress-bar{
    grid-column: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.progress-bar:hover{
    height: 15px;
}

.active-progress{
    background: var(--purple);
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.song-cover, .song-cover img{
    height: 75px;
    margin:0;
}

.song-cover, .song-details{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.song-details ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.song-details .song-name{
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;

}

.main-action > .btn-group button{
    width: 50px;
    background: var(--primary);
    border: 0;
    color:#aaa;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.main-action > .btn-group > button:nth-child(2n){
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(0.98);
    transition: all .1s ease;
}

.main-action > .btn-group > button:hover{
    transform: scale(1);
    color: #eee;
}

.main-action{
    justify-self: center;
}

.other-action{
    justify-self: end;
}

.volume-bar{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    background: var(--light-black);
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.volume{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background: var(--purple);
    height: 100%;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your typescript code as well? It would be the easiest for us if you merge all your code in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: rule number one when things don't work - read the console. press F12 on your browser and reload.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you put the app script. Try adding `/deep/` in front of some of your css. All angular files are containerised in their own object namespace.

For site wide stylings, I normally add a style.css directly into the index.html header

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the console log and check the error messages